# Boto3 Create Instance without a Key-Pair

Tags: python, boto3

I was wondering if there was a way to create an instance without a Key-Pair for testing purposes.

Comment: Instance limit reached has nothing to do with launching an instance without a keypair. Terminate the stopped instances or stop the running instances to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instannce without keypair however you will not be able to ssh into it or you can start it with ssm agent installed and running and use ec2 ssm service to send shell commands.

Comment: So would I just remove the KeyName variable? At this point all I want it to do is create the instance..but it won't do that without a KeyName. It just gives me an instance limit reached error.

Comment: Instance limit reached could be because you have reached the x number of instances in running status limit. I don't know understand what are you trying to achieve by catering an instance without keypair.

Comment: @MukeshSharma you are wrong. If an instance AMI has a known keypair baked in, you can still ssh in. I do this many times a day.

Comment: @helloV well not really,i was referring to public amis from the market place.

Comment: @MukeshSharma there is nothing in the question or in your answer that refers to marketplace AMIs. And many marketplace AMIs have ssh password, not keys.